# React Testing Library cleanup not working in Jest's describe bocks

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I have some work in progress tests, this is working as expected:

```js
describe("Parent", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    cleanup();
    jest.resetModules();
  });

  describe("Test 1", () => {
    const wrapper = render(
      <MockProvider>
        <MyComponent />
      </MockProvider>
    );

    test("1 ", () => {
      expect(wrapper.baseElement).toMatchSnapshot();
      expect(wrapper.getByText("Apply").disabled).toBe(true);
    });
  });

  describe("Test 2", () => {
    test("1 ", () => {
      const wrapper = render(
        <MockProvider>
          <MyComponent />
        </MockProvider>
      );
      console.log(wrapper.getByText("Apply").disabled);
      expect(1).toBe(1);
    });
  });
});
```

However when I move the 2nd render function out of the test it errors:

```js
describe("Parent", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    cleanup();
    jest.resetModules();
  });

  describe("Test 1", () => {
    const wrapper = render(
      <MockProvider>
        <MyComponent />
      </MockProvider>
    );

    test("1 ", () => {
      expect(wrapper.baseElement).toMatchSnapshot();
      expect(wrapper.getByText("Apply").disabled).toBe(true);
    });
  });

  describe("Test 2", () => {
    const wrapper = render(
      <MockProvider>
        <MyComponent />
      </MockProvider>
    );
    test("1 ", () => {
      console.log(wrapper.getByText("Apply").disabled);
      expect(1).toBe(1);
    });
  });
});
```

The error Im getting is

> Found multiple elements with the text: Apply

I can see in the console that the component is being rendered twice, so I think the cleanup function must not be working properly in regards to the describe block. This is weird as we already have Enzyme tests and the setup and tear down works fine for those.

Comment: Why are you trying to render in that way though?

Comment: It made sense to me that the describe block would set up case, and then test would have the assertions.

Comment: I'm not sure it works that way. I think every render has to be independent, you can't reuse them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was running into a separate problem, but in the midst found the likely answer to **your** problem.

Jest `describe` blocks run in sequence before any of the tests run. [Source](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown#order-of-execution-of-describe-and-test-blocks)

So you should basically never execute code in a describe block aside from variable scoping. If you need to set a variable or render a mock that is used across multiple tests, put it in a lifecycle method like `beforeAll` or `beforeEach`.

Answer (score 22):

To understand this we need to understand a little bit about how `Jest` runs our tests and how `React Testing Library` renders our components.

---

### Jest

Consider the code below and **try to guess what the output will be**:

```js
describe('First describe', () => {
  console.log('First describe');

  it('First test', () => {
    console.log('First test');
  });
});

describe('Second describe', () => {
  console.log('Second describe');

  it('Second test', () => {
    console.log('Second test');
  });
});
```

**Output (hover to see):**

> First describe
>
>     Second describe
>
>     First test
>
>     Second test

Note that all `describe` methods were initialised before the tests started to run.

This should already give you an idea of the problem, but let's now look at RTL.

---

### React Testing Library

Consider the code below and try to guess what the DOM will look like in the console:

```js
const Greeting = () => 'Hello world';

describe('First describe', () => {
  const wrapper = render(<Greeting />);

  it('First test', () => {
    console.log(wrapper.debug());
  });
});

describe('Second describe', () => {
  render(<Greeting />);
});
```

**Output (hover to see):**

> `<body>
>     <div>Hello world</div>
>     <div>Hello world</div>
>  </body>`

When we don't specify a base element to the `render` function, it always uses the same `document.body`

The `<div>` elements wrapping `Hello world` are added by RTL when we don't specify a custom container.

All RTL queries are bound to the base element by default--`document.body` in this case.

Therefore,

```js
getByText('Hello world'); // will find two elements and throw
```

This is how the [code in RTL](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/blob/master/src/pure.js#L24) looks like for the `render` function. (semi-pseudo code)

```js
if(!baseElement) {
  baseElement = document.body // body will be shared across renders
}
if(!container) {
  baseElement.appendChild(document.createElement('div')) // wraps our component
}
ReactDOM.render(component, container)

return {  container, baseElement, ...getQueriesForElement(baseElement)  }
```

### To solve this issue

Do one of the following:

1. call `render` inside the `it` or `test` methods
2. specify the `container` in the queries
3. specify a diferent base element for each `render`

Comment: wow your answer nails it for what i needed, thank you

Comment: This is a great answer! It would be great if each of the proposed solutions had a code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Another Quick fix for this could be wrapping your component with "React.Fragment" before passing it to `render()`

```
test ('should find text in <Component />', () => {
   const {getByText} = render (<><Component /></>)
   const divElement = getByText (/Find Text/i)
   expect (divElement).toBeInTheDocument ()
})
```